# Why my react bootstrap not working even after importing?

Tags: react-bootstrap

[image: this is the code]

[image: Here the bootstrap is not working]

I tried to reinstall the package but still the problem is not fixed.

Answer (score 3):

react-bootstrap is not shipped with any bootstrap-css:

https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/getting-started/introduction/#stylesheets

> Because React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of
> Bootstrap, we don't ship with any included CSS.

Install bootstrap as well and then put this in your App.jsx for example:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Or link to CDN package.